# A question on the coverings of lie groups.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $H$ be a group, $G$ be a connected Lie group, and $f: H \rightarrow G$ be a surjective group homomorphism with finite kernel in $Z(H)$. How to show that; $H$ has a unique structure as a Lie group such that $f$ is a homomorphism of Lie groups?

I'm trying to defing a topology on $H$ by defining a basis of $H$ by $f^{-1}(U)$, where $U$ is an open subset of $G$. In this way the topology is well defined, but the open sets in this basis are too big, I can't get a local homeomophism from a $f^{-1}(U)$ to $R^n$.

I have thought about using the kernel(let's denote the cardinality of the kernel by $m$) to cut each $f^{-1}(U)$ by $m$ part (just consider the transitive action of the kernel on any preimage $f^{-1}(g)$, and pick a representative for each $f^{-1}(g)$ to construct open subsets), and then define a topology. Such a topology seems to satisfy what we need, and we have a covering space(of multiplicity $m$) but it is not unique, since we have many ways to pick representatives to construct an open set.

I wonder if it is the right way to construct such a topology? How to understand the uniqueness? Thank you.

Comment: If $U\subset G$ is a small neighbourhood of $1\in G$ then you can get a natural lift of $U^m\subset G$ to $H$: just take $W:=(f^{-1}(U))^m\subset H$ (the $m$-th power of a subset here means the set of the $m$-th powers of its elements) and now $f:W\to U^m$ is a bijection. That way you'll get neighbourhoods of $1\in H$, and then you just translate them to every element of $H$.

Comment: @user8268 Thank you for your answer, but can you explain two things: 1. Why $U^m$ is open under your notation? 2. $m$ is the cardinality of the kernel, and I think $f|_{W}$ may not be a bijection? (For example, $e^{i\alpha i}\rightarrow e^{2\alpha i}$ $\alpha \in [0,2\pi]$ between two circles. Here $m=2$, and you can show that if $e^{2(2\alpha i)}=e^{2(2\beta i)}$ then $2\alpha$ need not to be equal to $2\beta$ )

Comment: $U$ needs to be "small" (say take a small open ball $B\subset\mathfrak g$ around $0$, s.t. exp is a diffeo from $B$ to its image, and set $U=\exp(B/m)$, so that $U^m=\exp(B)$). This will also address your example - $U$ should be given by $|\alpha|<\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ small enough; $f^{-1}(U)$ is composed of 2 arcs, but $(f^{-1}(U))^2$ is just one arc.

Comment: @user8268 I get it, thank you!